# New Cable Modem blocking TOR?

Tags: tor, cable-modem

I've been using the TOR browser bundle under Windows for several weeks now to watch British television while in the US. However, today I received a new cable modem/wireless router combo unit from TimeWarner Cable, and suddenly TOR no longer seems to be working properly.

I have in my config file:

```
StrictNodes 1
ExitNodes TorLand1,TorLand2
```

That config has been working great until today. The new unit is am Arris DG860A, not sure what the original modem was.

The test is that if I visit http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer then I can view the Radio player, but not the TV player, and am given the message that the content is locked to the UK region.

Comment: The NSA or GCH has probably [de-anonymized](http://allthingsd.com/20131004/why-the-nsa-hates-tor-the-network-that-protects-internet-anonymity/?mod=googlenews_editors_picks&google_editors_picks=true) you and figured out you're not in the UK.

Comment: Its very unlikely that the modem is blocking TOR traffic in the USA.

Comment: I thought so, too. And I appear to have a UK IP address and the ExitNode is working properly. But I can not for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: test it with the tor live cd. either you are leaking location info, or they have blocked known exit nodes. https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#LiveCD

Comment: Maybe BBC has their database updated to block that Tor exit node? Maybe try a different exit node located in UK?

Comment: When you use a service that reports your IP does it report your IP or a IP in the UK?

Comment: Hey - it reports a UK IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting I was able to find a TOR node that works. I'm still unsure why several nodes suddenly seemed to stop working. Perhaps as was said they have created a database of known TOR node IPs.